# Why dual rail PSU from AC instead of resistor divider?

Tags: voltage-divider

From theory I understand:
a simple class A transistor amplifier turns available voltage into higher voltage.

A simple resistor divider circuit provides + and - rails for powering opamps.

Instead of using this method to power opamps in synthesizers with a DC source, all the Eurorack schematics use an AC wallwart, rectify each half, then regulate them.

Doesn't this introduce ripple and unnecessary complexity? Can someone explain why my perception of theory doesn't meet common practice so that I don't have to find out by destroying my components? Thank you!

Comment: A simple voltage divider doesn't provide positive and negative rails, it just provides a half supply "virtual ground" so that op amps can work with AC signal without violating common mode input range.

Comment: How do you think a "DC source" is going to make DC from the AC mains? The same complexity is required, the same ripple is generated, whether the conversion takes place in the wall wart or in the equipment.

Comment: It is not quite correct to say that an amplifier "turns **available** voltage into higher voltage". An **input** voltage is converted to a higher voltage but the output voltage can not exceed the supply voltage.

Answer (score 2):

> From theory I understand: a simple class A transistor amplifier turns available voltage into higher voltage.

This statement seems to be unrelated to everything else in your post so I will not address it.

> A simple resistor divider circuit provides + and - rails for powering opamps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGafTg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Op-amps are almost without exception powered directly from the supply rails with no resistors in the power lines.*

No. The op-amps would be powered directly from the supply rails. A voltage divider might be used to provide an intermediate voltage level.

> Instead of using this method to power opamps in synthesizers with a DC source, all the Eurorack schematics use an AC wallwart, rectify each half, then regulate them.

> Doesn't this introduce ripple and unnecessary complexity?

No. Unregulated DC would have ripple. Good regulation will eliminate ripple to some specified level. (You didn't provide any sample schematics of a "Eurorack", whatever that is.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU9vYb.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. (a) Half-wave rectification enables split-rail DC from a two-terminal transformer secondary. (b) A full-wave split-rail rectification requires a centre-tapped transformer secondary.*

Answer (score 1):

A resistive divider won't work if you use different amount of current from positive and negative rails.

If you have any imbalance, it means current will flow into the midpoint voltage that is made with resistors, and thus the midpoint voltage will shift from the midpoint.

So, to have a real 0V midpoint voltage between positive and negative supplies, it requires that the positive voltage is regulated in reference to the 0V, and also that the negative voltage is regulated in reference to the 0V.

Comment: thank you for correctly interpreting my phrase "resistor divider" to the given task of providing dual supply rails. in all venues i have seen this task introduced immediately after the elementary voltage divider, so i am surprised to be so misunderstood by the other experts.

this does explain a "fault" with the method (one that can be ignored for some applications such as percussion synthesis, in minimal circuits it can be an advantage). i will have to think and experiment more with impedance and blow up some components before adopting the conventional method. thank you!